# Add custom configuration Element at runtime

Tags: c#, runtime, app-config, custom-configuration

Is it possible to add an custom configuration element at runtime.

Here is my app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="NodeList"
               type="Configuration.NodeListSection, NodeListConfiguration"
               requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <NodeList>
    <nodes>
      <add name="Dev1" isdefault="false" description ="Dev server" />
      <add name="QA1" isdefault="true" description="QA server"/>
      <add name="Prod1" isdefault="false" description="Production" />
    </nodes>
  </NodeList>
</configuration>
```

Can we add more nodes at runtime using C# code.

Comment: This does not look like a standard .NET configuration file. Where did you get this schema from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be from a built-in configuration section. You will find that "NodesList" is an section/element that is custom written. To determine where in your codebase it is coming from look for "NodesList" at the top of your config file in the `configSections` element. That will point you at the class to look into.

After that, you need the class to support write operations properly.

To learn a lot more about customising configuration files there is a [great series at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx) on the topic. In particular, the section on [Saving Configuration Changes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx#savingchanges) should be helpful to you.

**Edit (after more info added to question):**

Try something like (of course it all depends on what's in NodeListSection codebase):

```
using Configuration;

var nodeListSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("NodeList") as Configuration.NodeListSection;
var newNode = new NodeElement() { Name = "xyz", IsDefault = false, Description = "New Guy" };
nodeListSection.Nodes.Add(newNode);

Configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am not able to find the Add method to add a new NodeElement. nodeListSection.Nodes.Add(newNode);

Comment: Hmmm, you'll have to poke around whatever type "Nodes" is to work it out. Most likely it's a derivative of ConfigurationElementCollection -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.aspx - which means that the BaseAdd is protected unless explicitly overridden making your task a little harder...

Comment: I was able to add a public method and pass the element to the protected overriden, but after saving I don't see the changes in the App.config file.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx#t3_1 and scroll down a little to see some discussion on modified states and the `Unmerge` operation. That might help point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

The file you have posted does not look like a normal .NET config file, but a custom XML file.

In either case - `.config` files are just XML files - you can open, manipulate and save them using any of the XML libraries within the BCL, such as [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).

However, if you want to make changes to configuration during runtime, you will need to decide whether the application should apply these changes at runtime as well and code for this, as normally a configuration file will only be read at startup.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void AddNewKey_Config(string key, string value, string fileName)
    {
        var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(fileName);
        configFile.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value);
        configFile.Save();
    }
```

Comment: You can use this code for add new key and value in your configuration file.